# Trouble updating last document from a query

Tags: mongodb

Hello I'm new to Mongodb, I am currently trying to update the last document in a query result but having trouble doing so.

I know how to get the last document using

```
 db.collection.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1)
```

but how do I update this? I tried doing:

```
 db.collection.update(db.collection.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1))
```

But that didn't work. And I don't think:

```
 db.collection.update(query,update,option).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1))
```

would do what i want. I checked the official documentation but couldn't find anything on querying only for the last document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify) to perform an update that requires sorting to identify the document to update:

```js
db.test.findAndModify({
    query: {},
    sort: {$natural: -1},
    update: {$set: {foo: 'bar'}}
})
```

Comment: Can you do this in the `update` query itself  without using the `findAndModify` or by first `find` the document and then call the `update` function (as explained in the answers here)? In short, can we write the same query in the `query` (first) parameter of the `update` function and update the document?

Comment: @TempO'rary You can, but just understand that's two separate operations so it's no longer atomic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
var id = db.collection.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1)[0]['_id'];
db.collection.update({_id: id},{...})
```

Comment: This has the possibility of a change to the document interleaving between the find and update operations.