# Update last object inside array

Tags: mongodb

Support that I have the following strcuture of object, how can I only update the last object inside array? I cannot find the solution can be solved by one `updateOne` statement.

```
{
   history:[
       {online: "2019-05-27", offline: null},
       {online: "2019-05-27", offline: null}           <- only want to update this record
  ]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
   history:[
       {online: "2019-05-27", offline: null},
       {online: "2019-05-27", offline: "2019-05-27"}   
  ]
}
```

Comment: It seems it's already answered... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869638/trouble-updating-last-document-from-a-query